# XNA dropshadow?

Tags: xna

How can I make a dropshadow effect around a rectangle that I made out of primitives (line-strips) in XNA? I am currently making my rectangle by putting the primitives through a batch I made, and then adding textures as their background. These rectangles are supposed to symbolize "windows".

I want them to have a cool drop shadow as well.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

easiest way? first render your object as a black silhouette, slightly offset in the opposite direction of your light source. Then when you render your object on top of it, you will have a nice little drop shadow. This is a very simple and low effort technique.

Comment: +1 this can work for 2d drop-shadows as well; just draw the sprite with `Color.Black` and an offset, and then draw the real sprite on top.

Answer (score 2):

Exaclty what Joel Martinez said, also you can add transparency to shadow if you are using AlphaBlend:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, location, Color.Black * 0.5f);
```